# uint32_t in struct not working as expected

Tags: c++, struct, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to read the header of a bitmap file, using `struct`s, but the `uint32_t` members do not contain the expected value.

The start of the file contains this data:
`424d 36e6 0100 0000`

**Minimal Example:**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

struct s1 {
  uint16_t v16;
  uint32_t v32;
};
s1 structvar;

struct s2 {
  uint16_t v16_1;
  uint16_t v16_2;
  uint16_t v16_3;
};
s2 structvar2;

uint16_t v16;
uint32_t v32;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  myFile = SD.open("IMAGE001.BMP", FILE_READ);
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("Struct1");
    myFile.read(&structvar,6);
    Serial.println(structvar.v16);
    Serial.println(structvar.v32);

    myFile.seek(0);
    Serial.println("Struct2");
    myFile.read(&structvar2,6);
    Serial.println(structvar2.v16_1);
    Serial.println(structvar2.v16_2);
    Serial.println(structvar2.v16_3);

    myFile.seek(0);
    Serial.println("Separate vars");
    myFile.read(&v16,2);
    myFile.read(&v32,4);
    Serial.println(v16);
    Serial.println(v32);   

    myFile.close(); 
  }
}

void loop() {
  // nothing happens after setup finishes.
  delay(100);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Struct1
19778    //0x4d42
1        //0x00000001 - Lower half only
4        //4 Bytes - correct size.

Struct2
19778    //0x4d42
58934    //0xe636 - Upper Half
1        //0x0001 - Lower Half

Separate vars
19778    //0x4d42
124470   //0x0001e636 - Correct
```

So, it looks like the `uint_32_t` members of the structs only contain the lower half of the (little-endian) data, whereas if I read the `uint_32_t` as 2x`uint16_t`, or if I read the `uint16_t` & `uint32_t` values separately, then they contain the correct data

What am I missing? Is this something to do with packing?

Comment: Structures have padding. It's not 1:1 relationship with memory. There can be any number of unused, padding bytes between every two structure members. Best solution: read into a char array and deserialize the number byte by byte, taking care of proper alignment issues and endianess.

Comment: @KamilCuk. Thanks. Yes, I assumed that this was probably the case. But how does that explain this error? The file does _not_ have padding, so if the first two members of the struct are a `uint16_t` followed by a `uint32_t`, surely those members, when accessed, should correspond to the first two bytes, and then the next four bytes of the file?

Comment: Outputting each element separately is probably cleaner. You _do_ have padding in your struct(s). (e.g. in `s1`, `v16` is at offset 0. But, `v32` is at offset 4 (and _not_ at offset 2). This is because `v16` gets padded to allow for natural (i.e. 4 byte) alignment of `v32`. If you need to get rid of this padding [useful when dealing with hardware devices], you may want to consider adding `__attribute__((__packed__))` to your struct definitions.

Comment: In general, compilers align field to a multiple of their size. For instance, an int is at an address x4. But this is architecture and compiler dependent. You must never assume that you now the size of structs and always use sizeol(struct foo) in your reads.

Comment: Theoretically: There can be _any_ number of padding bytes between two structure members. So `offsetof(struct s1, v32)` could be equal to 1000. Practically: On a sanity compiler with 32 bit architecture the alignof of variables is usually 32 bit. So offsetof(struct s1, v32)` is probably equal to 4. There are 2 padding bytes betwen the end of `v16` and beginning of `v32` inside `struct s1`. `first two bytes` - now, as you come to _number_ the bytes, do you number bytes in the file/variables using little endian or big endian? The output looks ok, your machine is little endian.

Comment: OK. I _think_ perhaps I understand. If I read six bytes (or `sizeof(s1)`) bytes into `s1`, the read puts contiguous data into the memory allocated to the struct, so any data which coincides with with padding bytes will be lost? So using a struct is entirely the wrong thing to do here, although I thought that this is precisely the sort of thing they were for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are having alignment optimization affecting your code. You should use something like this

```
#pragma pack(push, 1) // one byte alignment
struct s1 {
  uint16_t v16;
  uint32_t v32;
};
struct s2 {
  uint16_t v16_1;
  uint16_t v16_2;
  uint16_t v16_3;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

also you can improve reads like in the below to not manually do everything

```
myFile.read(&structvar2, sizeof(structvar2));
```

Comment: Thanks. That sorted it. Will mark as correct when I am able. ironically, I was using `sizeof(struct)` in the reads, but noted that the because of padding, sizeof was larger than the actual data in the file, and thought that I would end up with the file pointer being in the wrong place, so I changed it. Clearly I am still learning here.